# python ATM loop trouble

Tags: python

I have written this program and cant seem to figure out how to get the program to loop back to the beginning and ask the 'choice' option again.

The program runs fine, everything prints to the screen, even the part that asks if you would like another transaction, how do I get this to loop back?

> Write ATM program. Enter account balance, print beginning balance.
>   ask for deposit or withdrawl, depending on selection, call function
>   to perform the action they wish, then print new balance. (Use iteration)

```
def withdraw():
    amt = int(input("What amount to withdraw - multiples of $20: "))
    print('New balance: $', balance - amt)


def deposit():
    amt = int(input("How much are you depositing? "))
    print('New balance: $',balance + amt)

def bal():
    return(balance)


print ("Hello, Welcome to Python ATM.")

balance = float(65.01)

pin = int(input("please enter your account number (Any number:) "))

print('''Current balance: $''',balance)

choice = int(input('''
Please choose an option from the following:
1 - Withdraw
2 - Deposit
3 - Check Balance
4 - Exit:  '''))


if choice == 1:
    print(withdraw());
elif choice == 2:
    print(deposit());
elif choice == 3:
    print(bal());

more = input("Would you like another transaction? (y/n)")
```

Comment: what python version are you using? and what traceback do you get?

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the error

Comment: use a while loop to make your code loop back.

Comment: Sorry, meant to correct this.  I changed the code and got rid of the traceback error, now I was just looking on how to write the loop for this. Also I am using python 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need a loop to repeat the choice :

```
while True:
    print('''Current balance: $''',balance)

    choice = int(input('''
Please choose an option from the following:
1 - Withdraw
2 - Deposit
3 - Check Balance
4 - Exit:  '''))


    if choice == 1:
        print(withdraw());
    elif choice == 2:
        print(deposit());
    elif choice == 3:
        print(bal());


    more = input("Would you like another transaction? (y/n)")
    if more.lower() != 'y':
        print("Goodbay")
        break
```

Comment: you can't really say `(y/n)` and also exit on anything other than `n` :)

Comment: @ReutSharabani you are right man but I was really bothered on taking in account that cycle too :)